# vundle/YouCompleteme: requires Vim 7.3.584+

Tags: vim

I have a error when i use vim. After I place this line in `.vimrc`

```
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
```

and

```
:PluginInstall
```

error:

```
YouCompleteMe unavailable:
```

My vim : VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3

Anyone's know how to fix it ?v

Comment: Well, your question lacks a lot of details. What is your exact Vim version, for example? What platform? How did you install it? YCM explicitly requires a version superior to 7.3.584: you probably get that error because your version doesn't match. Install a proper version to fix that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:version` command tells you the exact Vim version. If you grabbed the official installer from [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/), you probably have `7.3.000`. As Vim 7.4 has been released, it's the easiest to upgrade to that version.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the problem with Homebrew version on Mac, try the following as [officially documented](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe). Please make sure you're running `vim` not `vi` on your mac.

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
./install.sh
```